# Light bulbs randomly chosen

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, random-walk

In a room there are N light bulbs, initially they are all switched off. For N times, I do the following: I randomly choose one bulb and switch it on if it is off or switch it off if is on.

What is the probability that after my N actions all light bulbs are off?

The answer is 0 if N is odd. However when N is even I get a bit lost in the computations. I tried a brute force combinatorics approach but I failed. Then I thought of a random walk where each state is the number of light bulbs switched on. This provides me with an algorithm to compute the probability but I cannot find a closed form

Comment: 0 if N is odd..

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: thanks @mathworker21 indeed 0 if N is odd. However when N is even I get a bit lost in the computations. I tried a brute force combinatorics approach but I failed. Then I thought of a random walk where each state is the number of light bulbs switched on. This provides me with an algorithm to compute the probability but I cannot find a closed form

Comment: @FFF try to solve the general problem of $M$ light bulbs and $N$ flips via induction. This should definitely be doable.

Comment: Why do you think there is a "nice" solution?  I had the same idea as @mathworker21, but I'm not getting a simple form even in the case N=3.

Comment: Fair point @saulspatz. I am HOPING to find a nice closed form solution.

Comment: When $N=2,$ I get $\frac12.$  When $3$ switches are thrown $2k$ times, I get $$\frac12\left(\frac23\right)^{2k}\sum_{j=0}^k{2k\choose2j}4^{-j}$$ which doesn't seem to simplify.  It's possible that there's a nice solution when $N$ switches are thrown $N$ times, but I tend to doubt it.

Comment: N=2, p=1/2, since you will turn on 1 light and then you've got a 1/2 chance of turning off that same light. Call this (ON,OFF). N=4, p=1(1/4)1(1/4) +1 (3/4)(1/2)(1/4), since either you turn one light on and off (ON,OFF) or you turn 2 lights on and then turn those two lights off (ON,ON,OFF,OFF). N=6, p= (1/6)^3+ (1/6)(5/6)(2/6)(1/6)+...    (ON,OFF,ON,OFF,ON,OFF), (ON,OFF,ON,ON,OFF,OFF), (ON,ON,ON,OFF,OFF,OFF), (ON,ON,OFF,ON,OFF,OFF), etc. maybe use 1 and 0 for turning on and off and you need all binary sequences of size N that have exactly N/2 1s. Then compute the probability of each of these.

Comment: Saulspatz, unless I'm misunderstanding, for 3 switchs you must throw exactly 3 times, because the post says there are N bulbs and he throws the switch N times. so for 3 it is impossible.

Comment: So far I only managed to find a formula for N=2: 1/N, N=4: (N+3*N*(N-1))/N^4, and N=6: (N+15*N*(N-1)+15*N*(N-1)*(N-2))/N^6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of sequences of switches is $N^N$.

The number of sequences leaving all the lights off is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A209289 (Number of functions $f:\{\,1,2,\dots,2n\,\}\to\{\,1,2,\dots,2n\,\}$ such that every preimage has an even cardinality). Here $N=2n$. The formula $$a(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{2n} (n-i)^{2n}{\binom {2n}i}$$ and the estimate $$a(n) \sim {c  n^{2n}  2^{2n}  (1-r)^{2n} \over (2-r)^n  r^n  e^{2n}}$$ are given, where $r = 0.1664434403990353015638385297757806508596082\dots$ is the root of the equation $((2/r)-1)^{1-r} = e^2$, and $c = 1.66711311920192939687232294044843869828\dots$.

$N^N=(2n)^{2n}=2^{2n}n^{2n}$, so the probability is asymptotic to $${c    (1-r)^{2n} \over (2-r)^n  r^n  e^{2n}}=c\alpha^n$$ where $\alpha=(1-r)^2/((2-r)re^2)$.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(\ell,f)$ be the probability that $\ell$ bulbs are lit after $f$ flips. We want to find $p_N=P(0,N)$, where $N$ is the number of bulbs.

Note that $P(0,0)=1$, and if we let $P(-1,f)=P(N+1,f)=0$, we can find $P$ recursively*:

$$P(\ell,f)={N-\ell+1\over N}P(\ell-1,f-1)+{\ell+1\over N}P(\ell+1,f-1).$$

Mathematica calculations yield these results:

$\displaystyle p_2={1\over2}={2\over2^2}$,

$\displaystyle p_4={5\over32}={40\over4^4}$,

$\displaystyle p_6={47\over972}={2256\over6^6}$,

$\displaystyle p_8={1957\over131072}={250496\over8^8}$,

$\displaystyle p_{10}={35987\over7812500}={46063360\over10^{10}}$.

The sequence of numerators, $2, 40, 2256, 250496, 46063360, \dots$, is http://oeis.org/A209289, which as Gerry notes in his answer, counts the number of ways to flip the switches so ever switch if flipped an even number of times. And the sequence of denominators is the number of ways to flip switches $2N$ times if there are $2N$ switches in all.

*The two ways that $\ell$ bulbs can be lit after $f$ flips are:

- $\ell-1$ were lit after $f-1$ flips and we chose one of the $N-(\ell-1)$ unlit bulbs to switch.
- $\ell+1$ were lit after $f-1$ flips and we chose one of those $\ell+1$ to switch.